# Whenever I try to run Body() class using Add Stock button, it shows the error "Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Whenever I try to run Body() class using Add Stock button, it shows the error "Exception: ScrollView accepts only one widget" It was running fine before, but now I replced some textinputs and buttons from kivy to KivyMD. But haven't touched the Body() class yet. Nothing is changed

**.py file**

```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    
    import sys, time, threading
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from datetime import datetime
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import pandas as pd
    from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
    from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,ThreeLineListItem,ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
    from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget,ImageLeftWidget
    from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    import csv
    from os import path
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
    from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
    from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
    from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    import re
    from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
    from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
    import pandas as pd
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from functools import partial
    from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
    from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    
    # Window.size = (300,500)
    username =''
    
    class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                     RecycleGridLayout):
        ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''
    
    
    class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
        ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
        index = None
        selected = BooleanProperty(False)
        selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    
        txt_input = ObjectProperty(None)
        stock_name = ObjectProperty(None)
        stock_symbol = ObjectProperty(None)
        purchase_price = ObjectProperty(None)
        stop_loss = ObjectProperty(None)
    
        def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
            ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
            self.index = index
            return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
                rv, index, data)
    
        def on_touch_down(self, touch):
            ''' Add selection on touch down '''
            if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
                return True
            if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
                return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
    
        def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    
            ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
    
    
            self.selected = is_selected
            if is_selected:
    
                # App.get_running_app().root.widget_1.ids.txt_input1.text = str(rv.data[index].get("text"))
                xx =str(rv.data[index].get("text"))
                if (xx.find('(NSI)') != -1):
                    x,y = xx.split(" (NSI)")
                    add_sym = '.NS'
                else:
                    x,y = xx.split(" (BSE)")
                    add_sym = '.BO'
                print(xx)
                print(x)
    
                App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text = x
                f = pd.read_csv("Stock Tickers.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1", engine='python')
                fl = len(f.index)
                file = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['Symbols', 'Name', 'Exchange'])
    
    
                for i in range(fl):
                    for index in range(1):
                        columnSeriesObj_sym = file.iloc[:, 0]
                        columnSeriesObj1 = file.iloc[:, 1]
                        columnSeriesObj_ex = file.iloc[:, 2]
                        before_sym,b = columnSeriesObj_sym.values[i].split('.')
    
    
                        if columnSeriesObj1.values[i] == App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text:
                            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text = before_sym + add_sym
    
    
    
    
    class RV(RecycleView):
    
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    
    
    class DropDownWidget(GridLayout):
        txt_input = ObjectProperty()
        rv = ObjectProperty()
    
        stock_name = ObjectProperty(None)
        stock_symbol = ObjectProperty(None)
        purchase_price = ObjectProperty(None)
        stop_loss = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    
        def btn_input(self):
    
            end = datetime.today().date()
            start = end
    
    
            print("Stock Name:", App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text,
                  "Stock Symbol:", App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text)
            print("Purchase Price:", App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.purchase_price.text,
                  "Stop Loss(%):", App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stop_loss.text)
    
            # write data to csv file
    
    
            file_name = username + "_stoploss.csv"
            if path.exists(file_name):
                with open(file_name, "a+", newline='')as newFile:
                    fieldnames = ["Stock Name", "Stock Symbol", "Purchase Price", "Stop Loss(%)"]
                    newFileWriter = csv.DictWriter(newFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    newFileWriter.writerow({"Stock Name": App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text,
                                            "Stock Symbol": App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text,
                                            "Purchase Price": App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.purchase_price.text,
                                            "Stop Loss(%)": App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stop_loss.text})
    
            else:
                myFile = open(file_name, 'w+',newline='')
                myData = [["Stock Name", "Stock Symbol", "Purchase Price", "Stop Loss(%)"],
                          [App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text,
                           App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text,
                           App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.purchase_price.text,
                           App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stop_loss.text]]
    
                with myFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                    writer.writerows(myData)
    
            df = web.DataReader(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text, 'yahoo', start, end)
            print(df.tail())
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.txt_input.text = ""
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_name.text = ""
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stock_symbol.text = ""
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.purchase_price.text = ""
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('body_screen').widget_1.ids.stop_loss.text = ""
    
    
    class MyTextInput(TextInput):
        txt_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    
        flt_list = ObjectProperty()
        word_list = ListProperty()
        stock_name = ObjectProperty(None)
        stock_symbol = ObjectProperty(None)
        purchase_price = ObjectProperty(None)
        stop_loss = ObjectProperty(None)
        # this is the variable storing the number to which the look-up will start
        starting_no = NumericProperty()
        suggestion_text = ''
    
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
        def on_text(self, instance, value):
            # find all the occurrence of the word
    
            self.parent.ids.rv.data = []
            if len(value) != 0:
                matches = [word for word in self.word_list if word.lower().find(value.lower()) != -1]
    
            # display the data in the recycleview
                display_data = []
    
                for i in matches:
                    display_data.append({'text': i})
                self.parent.ids.rv.data = display_data
    
                # ensure the size is okay
                if len(matches) <= 10:
                    self.parent.height = (50 + (len(matches) * 20))
                else:
                    self.parent.height = 240
    
        def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
            if self.suggestion_text and keycode[1] == 'tab':
                self.insert_text(self.suggestion_text + ' ')
                return True
            return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
    
    
    class Body(Screen):
        def on_pre_enter (self, **kwargs):
            super(Body, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    
            f = pd.read_csv("Stock Tickers.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python')
            fl = len(f.index)
            file = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['Symbols', 'Name', 'Exchange'])
    
            wl = []
            for i in range(fl):
                for index in range(1):
    
                    columnSeriesObj = file.iloc[:, 1]
                    self.columnSeriesObj_ex = file.iloc[:, 2]
    
    
                    wl.append(columnSeriesObj.values[i] + " (" + self.columnSeriesObj_ex.values[i] + ")")
    
    
            tp = tuple(wl)
            print("File is loaded")
    
    
            self.widget_1 = DropDownWidget()
            self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.word_list = wl
            self.widget_1.ids.txt_input.starting_no = 3
            self.add_widget(self.widget_1)
    
    
    
    
    class Signin(Screen):
        user_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    
    
        def check(self,email):
            regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
            
            if (re.search(regex, email)):
                return True
    
            else:
                return False
    
    
        def btn(self):
            global username
            un = self.user_name.text
   
    class Option(Screen):
        def back(self):
            MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
            MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'signin_screen'
   
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(Signin(name='signin_screen'))
    sm.add_widget(Option(name='option_screen'))
    
    sm.add_widget(Body(name='body_screen'))
    
    
    class run1(MDApp):
    
        def build(self):
            kv = Builder.load_file("run1.kv")
            return kv
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        run1().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
ScreenManager:
    Signin:
    Option:
    Body:
    ListApp:



<Body>:
    name: 'body_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 188/255, 143/255, 145/255, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<DropDownWidget>:
    cols:2
    id: DropDownWidget
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:(1, 1, 1, 1)
    size_hint:(0.5,1)
    pos_hint :{'center_x':.43, 'center_y':.23}
    row_force_default : True
    row_default_height : 30
    col_force_default : True
    col_default_width : 250
    spacing: '20dp'

    stock_name: stock_name
    stock_symbol: stock_symbol
    purchase_price: purchase_price
    stop_loss: stop_loss

    txt_input: txt_input
    rv: rv
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Add Stock'
        type: "top"
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        md_bg_color:98/255,0,238/255,1
        elevation:8

    MyTextInput:
        id: txt_input


    RV:
        id: rv
        size_hint: 5.0 ,.1

    Label:
        text: "Stock Name: "

    TextInput:
        id: stock_name
        readonly: True
        multiline:False

    Label:
        text: "Stock Symbol: "

    TextInput:
        id: stock_symbol
        readonly: True
        multiline:False

    Label:
        text: "Purchase Price: "

    TextInput:
        id: purchase_price
        input_filter: 'int'
        multiline:False

    Label:
        text: "Stop Loss(%): "


    TextInput:
        id: stop_loss
        input_filter: 'int'
        multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Submit"

        on_press: root.btn_input()
    Button:
        text:"Back"

        on_press: root.parent.manager.current = 'option_screen'




<MyTextInput>:
    id: MyTextInput

    readonly: False
    multiline: False

<SelectableLabel>:

    id: SelectableLabel


    # Draw a background to indicate selection

    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1) if self.selected else (1, 0, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            # pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,.2

        Line:
            rectangle: self.x +8 , self.y, self.width - 2, self.height -2


    bar_width: 20
    scroll_type:['bars']
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        cols:1
        default_size: None, dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        multiselect: False
<Signin>:
    name: 'signin_screen'
    user_name: user_name


#    canvas:
#        Color:
#            rgba: 255/255,105/255,180/255,1
#        Rectangle:
#            size: self.size
#            pos: self.pos

#    spacing: '15dp'
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title:'SignIn'
        type: "top"
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        md_bg_color:98/255,0,238/255,1
        elevation:8
    MDTextField:

        id: user_name
        hint_text:'Email'

        icon_right: "email"
        mode:'rectangle'
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "Enter text"
#        fill_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
        halign:'center'
        helper_text_mode:'on_focus'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300
#        color_mode: 'custom'
#        line_color_focus: 98/255,0,238/255,1

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        icon: "login"
        text:"Submit"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
        halign:'center'
        custom_color:0,0,0,1

#            size_hint: .5 ,.3
        background_normal: ''
#            background_color: (255/255, 153/255, 71/255, 1)
        on_press :
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = 'option_screen'






<Option>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 138/255,43/255,226/255,.4
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    name: 'option_screen'

    orientation:'vertical'
    spacing: '20dp'
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Choose Option'
        type: "top"
        md_bg_color:229/255,33/255,101/255,1
        left_action_items: [["back button.png", lambda x: root.back()]]
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        elevation:8

    MDCard:
        md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:None,None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
        height:150
        width:150
        elevation:8

        MDIconButton:
            md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
            icon: "Add Stock.png"
            user_font_size: "100dp"
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_press : root.manager.current = 'body_screen'

        MDLabel:
            text:'Add Stock'
            font_size: "20dp"
            halign:'center'




    MDCard:
        md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:None,None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
        height:150
        width:150
        elevation:8

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "Check Stoploss.png"
            user_font_size: "100dp"
            halign:'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_press : root.manager.current = 'Stoploss_ip'

        MDLabel:
            text:'Check Stoploss'
            font_size: "20dp"
            halign:'center'
```

It is showing the folowing error..
**Error**

```
"D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Stoploss Calculator/run1.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Rushi Dada\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-12-25_64.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.5161'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.5161'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[WARNING] [Lang        ] The file D:\Stoploss Calculator\run1.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
File is loaded
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\run1.py", line 425, in <module>
     run1().run()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1198, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 297, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 138, in on_touch_down
     if super(ButtonBehavior, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripplebehavior.py", line 231, in on_touch_down
     return super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 961, in on_touch_down
     return super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\run1.kv", line 240, in <module>
     on_press : root.manager.current = 'body_screen'
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 498, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 545, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 600, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1154, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1056, in on_current
     self.transition.start(self)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 377, in start
     self.screen_in.dispatch('on_pre_enter')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\run1.py", line 243, in on_pre_enter
     self.widget_1 = DropDownWidget()
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\gridlayout.py", line 279, in __init__
     super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 359, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 541, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 661, in _apply_rule
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 541, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
     widget.add_widget(child)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recycleview\__init__.py", line 466, in add_widget
     super(RecycleView, self).add_widget(widget, *largs)
   File "D:\Stoploss Calculator\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 1152, in add_widget
     raise Exception('ScrollView accept only one widget')
 Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't call `super(Body, self).__init__(**kwargs)` in the `on_pre_enter()` method.

Comment: @john I tried that too. but the same error occurs. I also changed on_pre_enter() to build() but no luck

Comment: @John Anderson please help me to solve this issue. I have posted a question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371164/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recycleview-also-i-want-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The problem was In the KV file name. it was running multiple times. and Loading the same kv file more than once can lead to unexpected results and I was seeing one such result

My .py file name is run1.py and the KV file name was run1.kv and as you can see I am calling the kv = Builder.load_file("run1.kv") in class run1(MDApp). it is calling the kv file and also the kv file is autoamtically called by .py as it finds the same name.

so I renamed the kv file with stopl.kv and it solved the problem..